# The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times

Tags: cntk

To some degree during the Epoch, but then a lot once the Epoch finishes, I'm seeing this warning about copying an empty matrix. What typically causes this warning?

`01/23/2017 13:06:49:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691301-691400]: ce = 0.06757763 * 9404; errs = 1.595% * 9404; time = 14.3775s; samplesPerSecond = 654.1
01/23/2017 13:07:04:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691401-691500]: ce = 0.08411693 * 9784; errs = 1.962% * 9784; time = 15.1554s; samplesPerSecond = 645.6
01/23/2017 13:07:18:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691501-691600]: ce = 0.07443892 * 9847; errs = 1.696% * 9847; time = 14.1284s; samplesPerSecond = 697.0
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
01/23/2017 13:07:33:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691601-691700]: ce = 0.07692308 * 9815; errs = 1.854% * 9815; time = 14.4867s; samplesPerSecond = 677.5
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
01/23/2017 13:07:48:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691701-691800]: ce = 0.08028341 * 9809; errs = 1.906% * 9809; time = 14.7772s; samplesPerSecond = 663.8
01/23/2017 13:08:03:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691801-691900]: ce = 0.09192892 * 10073; errs = 2.214% * 10073; time = 14.8481s; samplesPerSecond = 678.4
01/23/2017 13:08:17:  Epoch[ 1 of 50]-Minibatch[691901-692000]: ce = 0.07414725 * 9616; errs = 1.841% * 9616; time = 14.9059s; samplesPerSecond = 645.1
01/23/2017 13:08:32: Finished Epoch[ 1 of 50]: [Training] ce = 0.08177092 * 67573150; errs = 1.962% * 67573150; totalSamplesSeen = 67573150; learningRatePerSample = 0.0020000001; epochTime=104968s
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.
WARNING: The same matrix with dim [0, 0] has been transferred between different devices for 20 times.`

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this with an empty matrix, but when the matrix has non-zero dimensions this is caused by an unsupported operation in the GPU (typically a computation involving sparse matrices either in the forward or the backward pass). The message can typically be triggered by long recurrences where on each step the troublesome operation keeps adding one more GPU-CPU-GPU roundtrip to the matrix in question.